# adding geolocation to an existing google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

hi I'm working on a map based on this example http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_categories.htm and trying to add geolocation to it but every time i try to add the code for geolocation it breaks the rest of the code, so i'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction on how to get it working

I am new to google maps and geolocation

and i'm sorry if this question as been asked before i just can't find the answer i need

this is the code i am using for my index.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/downloadxml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/map.js"></script>
</head>

 <body onload="initialize()">
 <div class="main-container">
 <img class="logo" src="images/testlogo.png" width="1000" height="150">
 <div class="overall">

 <div class="sidebar1">
 <p>Home</p>
 <p>About Us</p>
 <p>Contact Us</p>
 <p>My Portfolio</p>
 <p>Links</p>
 </div>

 <div class="sidebar2">

 <p>Hi My name is Robert Baron Austin and I'm the designer of this website and other sites like Spinfish.co.uk which was my first ever website that I handcoded by myself by using Dreamweaver, Photoshop and Illustrator.</p>

 </div>

 <div class="content1">

 <p>Hi My name is Robert Baron Austin and I'm the designer of this website and other sites like Spinfish.co.uk bacwhich was my first ever website that I handcoded by myself by using Dreamweaver, Photoshop and Illustrator.</p>

 </div>

 <div class="content2">

 <p>Hi My name is Robert Baron Austin and I'm the designer of this website and other sites like Spinfish.co.uk which was my first ever website that I handcoded by myself by using Dreamweaver, Photoshop and Illustrator.</p>

 </div>

 <div class="content3">

 <p>Hi My name is Robert Baron Austin and I'm the designer of this website and other sites like Spinfish.co.uk which was my first ever website that I handcoded by myself by using Dreamweaver, Photoshop and Illustrator.</p>

 </div>

 <div class="content4">

 <p class="images1"><img class="otherpics" src="../f5770309.jpg" width="150" height="150"></p>
 <p>Hi My name is Robert Baron Austin and I'm the designer of this website and other sites like Spinfish.co.uk which was my first ever website that I handcoded by myself by using Dreamweaver, Photoshop and Illustrator.</p>
 </div>

 <div class="content5">

 <p>Hi My name is Robert Baron Austin and I'm the designer of this website and other sites like Spinfish.co.uk which was my first ever website that I handcoded by myself by using Dreamweaver, Photoshop and Illustrator.</p>

 </div>

 <div class="content6">

 <p><div id="map"></div>

 <form class="form" action="#">
   Theatres: <input type="checkbox" id="theatrebox" onclick="boxclick(this,'theatre')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
   Golf Courses: <input type="checkbox" id="golfbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'golf')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
   Test: <input type="checkbox" id="testbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'test')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
   Tourist Information: <input type="checkbox" id="infobox" onclick="boxclick(this,'info')" /><br />
 </form></p>

<div id="side_bar"></div>

 </div>



 </div>


 <div class="footer">footer</div>

 </div></div></body>
 </html>
```

and this is the javascript

```
//<![CDATA[
  // this variable will collect the html which will eventually be placed in the side_bar 
  var side_bar_html = ""; 

  var gmarkers = [];
  var gicons = [];
  var map = null;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
 { 
  size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
  });


  var iconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('mapIcons/marker_red.png',
   // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
   new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
   // The origin for this image is 0,0.
   new google.maps.Point(0,0),
   // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
   new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
  var iconShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
   // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
   // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
   new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
   new google.maps.Point(0,0),
   new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
   // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
   // The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
   // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
   // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
   // coordinate.
   var iconShape = {
   coord:   [9,0,6,1,4,2,2,4,0,8,0,12,1,14,2,16,5,19,7,23,8,26,9,30,9,34,11,34,11,30,12,26,13,24,14,21,16,18,18,16,20,12,20,8,18,4,16,2,15,1,13,0],
  type: 'poly'
  };

    //Custom marker function
        function createMarker(point) {

    //Create the markers
        return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        map: map,
        draggable: false

    });

 }

  // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
  function createMarker(latlng,name,html,category) {
  var contentString = html;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    icon: gicons[category],
    shadow: iconShadow,
    map: map,
    title: name,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
    });
    // === Store the category and name info as a marker properties ===
    marker.mycategory = category;                                 
    marker.myname = name;
    gmarkers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
 }

  // == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
  function show(category) {
    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
        gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
      }
    }
    // == check the checkbox ==
    document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = true;
  }

  // == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
  function hide(category) {
    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
        gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }
    // == clear the checkbox ==
    document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = false;
    // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
    infowindow.close();
  }

  // == a checkbox has been clicked ==
  function boxclick(box,category) {
    if (box.checked) {
      show(category);
    } else {
      hide(category);
    }
    // == rebuild the side bar
    makeSidebar();
  }

  function myclick(i) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i],"click");
  }


  // == rebuilds the sidebar to match the markers currently displayed ==
  function makeSidebar() {
    var html = "";
    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (gmarkers[i].getVisible()) {
        html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + gmarkers[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = html;
  }

 function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
   zoom: 10,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.8363,-3.0377),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);


  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    });



  // Read the data
  downloadUrl("categories.xml", function(doc) {
  var xml = xmlParse(doc);
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      // obtain the attribues of each marker
      var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
      var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var html = "<b>"+name+"<\/b><p>"+address;
      var category = markers[i].getAttribute("category");
      // create the marker
      var marker = createMarker(point,name,html,category);
    }

    // == show or hide the categories initially ==
    hide("theatre");
    hide("golf");
    hide("info");
    hide("test");
    // == create the initial sidebar ==
    makeSidebar();
  });
 }

 // This Javascript is based on code provided by the
 // Community Church Javascript Team
 // http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/   
 // http://econym.org.uk/gmap/
 // from the v2 tutorial page at:
 // http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_categories.htm
 //]]>
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific in what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I'm trying to add geolocation to the map in my version of the website linked above, so when a user comes onto my website they will be presented with their location and then can select from a list of places of interest

Answer (score 0):

For a start you have to use `sensor=true` when including the Google Maps API

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

Comment: oh ok thanks barrio, do i have the coding in the right place I think that is part of my problem

Comment: still having a problem with this i just can't seem to get it going